# Change the name of module class in SWIG

Tags: java, c#, python, swig

Is there a way to rename the module class, which has the definitions for globals?

I know that it's possible to rename the class with native calls - from `<modulename>PINVOKE` in C#, and from `<modulename>JNI` in Java, but can't find a way to rename module class, which always gets `<modulename>` name.